# c programming function doesn’t return false

Tags: c

```
     #include "ctype.h"
     #include "string.h"
     #include "stdbool.h"
     #include "stdio.h"

   int check_for_sub_string(char s[],char word[])
  {
   int flag = false;
   char mark[]=" ";
   char *tok;
   tok = strtok(s,mark);
   while (tok!=NULL)
   {
    tok= strtok(NULL,mark);
    if (strcmp(tok,word)==0)
    {
        flag= true;
        return flag;
    }
    else flag = false;

   }return flag;
  }
```

Supposedly, it is meant to check if a substring is in a string when I run the code with a word which is not in the string it doesn't return 0.  I don't know why. For instance, I run it with s[]="this is a test string", and word[]="kol", it doesn't return 0. I put the return flag at the end of the loop so if it doesn't find the word to return false.

Comment: Not exactly related, but this function will "destroy" its input `s`. Not a very desirable side-effect for a function asking to "check" something. Not speaking of the fact it won't work with string literals.

Comment: to simplify your code you can replace `flag= true; return flag;` by `return true;` and remove the variable *flag* everywhere and at the end replace `return flag;`by `return false;`

Comment: A little nitpicking about the code you show (unrelated to your problem): First please use angle-brackets `<>` for system headers. Secondly, if you want to return a bool result, make the return type an actual `bool` instead. Thirdly, when called the function call `strtok` twice in a row (which actually is a little related to your problem), you might want to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of the function. Lastly the variable `flag` isn't needed at all.

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuild your loop like this:

```
for (tok = strtok(s,mark);
     tok!=NULL;
     tok = strtok(NULL,mark))
{
      .....
}
```

This will check `tok` for being not-NULL before use on every iteration.

Comment: Using untested pointer is an error. Using the `flag` variable is not. May be it's inefficient, suboptimal or whatever your call it - but it does not lead to incorrect results.

Comment: @CiaPan *flag* makes the code complicated for nothing, so less readable. The more we can help OP the better it is. (out of that strange DV, done without saying why, not from me)

Comment: @bruno IMHO a 'complication for nothing' is a weakness, but not an error. Reducing unnecessary complication is optimization or beautifying the code, not fixing it. I gave a fix, because OP asks for help to fix the code. If they need to optimize it, they may also ask at CodeReview SE.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't return false because it crashes (or at least invokes undefined behavior): when you get to the end of the string, `strtok` returns NULL, but you immediately pass that NULL pointer to `strcmp`. The test `tok != NULL` doesn't happen until the loop body gets to the end, and that's too late.

Comment: `tok= strtok(NULL,mark);` is in the wrong place in the loop. Move it to the other end.

Comment: @EliorMizrhi look also at the remarks we did on your question ;)